# Is it possible class instance with this method?

Tags: python, class, instance

```
class Category:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.ledger = ['','','']

    def deposit(self, amount, description=''):
        self.amount = amount
        self.description = description
        self.ledger[0] = {"amount": amount, "description": description}

    def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount,description=''):
        self.withdraw_amount = withdraw_amount
        self.description = description
        self.ledger[1] = {"amount": -withdraw_amount, "description": description}

    def transfer(self, transfer_amount, budget_category=''):
        self.transfer_amount = transfer_amount
        self.ledger[2] = {"amount": -transfer_amount, "description": "Transfer to " + 
                           budget_category
```

Even now I don't understand how I use bank accounts function only with one class.
Everything is OK except for money transfer function.
**When I transfer money to another category I have to make class variable ledger with this way**

If the money is 500:

```
food = Category('Food')
food.deposit(1000)
cloth = Category('Clothing')
food.transfer(500,'Clothing')
```

And the result is:

```
food.ledger[2] = {"amount": -500, "description": "Transfer to Clothing"}
clothing.ledger[0] = {"amount": 500, "description": "Transfer from Food"}
```

How is it possible to run `cloth.deposit()` when `food.transfer()` run at once? Is it impossible or just is my code wrong? I need help.

Comment: Instead of passing a string for the budget category, pass the other `Category` object. Then fix the method so that it expects to receive that object and does something useful.

Comment: Change the `transfer()` method so it receives `source` and `destination` category objects as argument (along with amount). It can then call the corresponding `deposit()` and `withdraw()` method of each one to carry out the transaction.